# Passing list of named parameters to function?

Tags: r

I want to write a little function to generate samples from appropriate distributions, something like:

```
makeSample <- function(n,dist,params)
values <- makeSample(100,"unif",list(min=0,max=10))
values <- makeSample(100,"norm",list(mean=0,sd=1))
```

Most of the code works, but I'm having problems figuring out how to pass the named parameters for each distribution.  For example:

```
params <- list(min=0, max=1)
runif(n=100,min=0,max=1) # works
do.call(runif,list(n=100,min=0,max=1)) # works
do.call(runif,list(n=100,params)) # doesn't work
```

I'm guessing I'm missing a little wrapper function somewhere but can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Almost there: try

```
do.call(runif,c(list(n=100),params))
```

Your variant, `list(n=100,params)` makes a list where the second element is your list of parameters.  Use `str()` to compare the structure of `list(n=100,params)` and `c(list(n=100),params)` ...

Comment: Just would like to add a comment that: the c() operation essentially expands/extends an existing list--ie, list(n=100)--by adding the items from a second list--ie, params.

Answer (score 15):

`c(...)` has a concatenating effect, or in FP parlance, a flattening effect, so you can shorten the call; your code would be:

```
params <- list(min=0, max=1)
do.call(runif, c(n=100, params))
```

Try the following comparison:

```
params = list(min=0, max=1)
str(c(n=100, min=0, max=1))
str(list(n=100, min=0, max=1))
str(c(list(n=100),params))
str(c(n=100,params))
```

Looks like if a list is in there at any point, the result is a list ( which is a desirable feature in this use case)

Answer (score 4):

[rlang::exec](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/exec.html) enables dynamic dots on any function.

```
args <- list(x = c(1:10, 100, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
rlang::exec(mean, !!!args)
```