# How to pass a list of arguments to partially match a function's parameters?

Tags: r

I want to pass a list to partially match a function's parameters. I am looking for syntax of equivalent simplicity as the `do.call` method here: [Passing list of named parameters to function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129673/passing-list-of-named-parameters-to-function)

Here is an example (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15059219/2109289), where calling `mapply(FUN, ...)` requires the data frame columns to be passed one by one to `...`:

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(3,4), z=c(5,6))
> df
  x y z
1 1 3 5
2 2 4 6
> mapply(function(x,y) x+y, df$x, df$z)
[1] 6 8
```

Wouldn't it be nice if you could just pass the data frame `df[, c("x", "z")]` as an argument?

E.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(3,4), z=c(5,6))
do.call(function(x, y) mapply(function(x,y) x+y, x, y), unname(df[, c("x", "z")]))
# [1] 6 8
do.call(function(...) mapply(function(x,y) x+y, list(...)[[1]], list(...)[[2]]), df[, c("x", "z")])
# [1] 6 8
```

Is there a better way of doing this instead of creating a closure to be passed to `do.call`?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be

```
unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = `+`, df[c('x', 'z')])))
#[1] 6 8
```

Or using `mapply`

```
do.call(mapply, c(FUN = `+`, df[c('x', 'z')]))
#[1] 6 8
```

Comment: or `do.call("+", df[, c("x", "z")])`

Comment: @baptiste  or `Reduce('+', df[c('x', 'z')])`

Comment: Thanks, looks useful, but I am not sure how this will hold up for a more general function. I.e., for a general function `f <- function(x1, x2, x3, ...)`, be able to call it like `f(x1, x2, arg_list)`.

Comment: @Alex The `f` or `FUN` takes a function as argument.  So, I don't know what is the problem here.

Comment: my problem is that to use a list in a function, either explicitly call each element of the list for each function parameter, or, create a complete list of function arguments to be then passed to `do.call` (your second solution). I am wondering whether there is a middle ground where you don't have to do this.

Comment: @Alex If you have a different problem, then the question should have been different.  Here, I am answering the question you posted.  Also, you must have noticed that the `+` can be called more easier than with `mapply` (from the comments)

Comment: I will think about this a bit more and edit the question. Thanks.