# Use vector of strings representing variables generated by a for loop as variable in function call

Tags: r

I would like to call a `function()` in R using variable names out of a string vector. In my specific case I used a for loop to generate numbered variable names. For example:

```
    for (i in 1:3) {
        assign(paste0("x",i),"value")
    }
    v <- paste0("x",c(1,2,3))

    function(v) #Here I would like to call function with variables defined in for loop.
```

Background:
I have a data frame, which I filter by different criteria (controls, cases). The resulting vectors are turned into Grange objects and saved as variable or saved as a string vector of directories. Then I would like to call `IDRfilterN3()` using the same number of Grange objects and paths. This function expects 3 Grange objects and 3 paths.

Here the specific example:

```
for (i in unique(samples$Treatment)){
  ind <- samples$Treatment == i
  for (j in samples$Replicate[ind]){
    assign(paste0("peaks_",i,"_",j),toGRanges(file.path(samples$Peaks[ind][j]),format = "MACS2")) 
    assign(paste0("bam_",i,"_",j),file.path(samples$bamReads[ind][j])) 
  }
  if(length(samples$Replicate[ind])==3) assign(paste0("peaks_",i,".idr"),IDRfilterN3(paste0("peaks_",i,"_",c(1,2,3)),paste0("bam_",i,"_",c(1,2,3))))
  else print("Sample size not applicable. IDR failed!")
}
```

Here an example of a sample sheet and the steps I need to perform:

```
    ids <- paste0("ID",c(1,2,3,4))    
    condition <- c(rep("A",2),rep("B",2))
    replicate <- c(1,2,1,2)
    pathA <- paste0("/dir/sample_",c(1,2,3,4))
    pathB <- paste0("/dir/sample_",c(1,2,3,4),".bam")
    d <- data.frame(ids,condition,replicate,pathA,pathB)

    #Generate variable storing Grange object out of pathA path for each condition and replicate:
    peakA1 <- toGRanges("/dir/sample_1")
    peakA2 <- toGRanges("/dir/sample_2")
    peakB1 <- toGRanges("/dir/sample_3")
    peakB2 <- toGRanges("/dir/sample_4")

    #Call IDR function for each condition (A, B) using the replicate variables and the path from column pathB
    IDRfilterN3(peakA1, peakA2, "/dir/sample_1.bam", "/dir/sample_2.bam")
    IDRfilterN3(peakB1, peakB2, "/dir/sample_3.bam", "/dir/sample_4.bam")
```

Thanks for your input.

Comment: You mean you want to do `function(v)` instead of `function(x1,x2,x3)`?

Comment: In my experience it is almost always better to use a named list than `assign` a bunch of variables. Care to share the larger context for your question? What are the variables being used for?

Comment: Yes essentially call function(v).

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129673/passing-list-of-named-parameters-to-function) may be helpful.

Comment: Yikes this seems like a very inefficient operation for R. Are you trying to directly translate some code in another language into R? It would be better to talk about what you are really trying to accomplish rather than having us fix how you decided to do it. There may be better ways in R. A proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Yes, I assumed my code is inefficient, but always striving to learn - so no not translated. I have a samplesheet containing information about samples (e.g. different conditions, raw data file paths, replicate ID). Now, I would like to call function IDRfilterN3 for each set of samples (replicates 1,2, ... n) belonging to a given condition (e.g. "liver"). Will work on a reproducible example.