# Passing a list of named parameters with NULL value to a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm writing a wrapper function for `dplyr::summarize` to add a summary row to a data frame. The goal is to provide the data frame, columns you'd like to summarize, the summary  function, and any additional arguments for that function. Currently, the function works as long as `args` is not `NULL`. If no additional arguments are supplied, the function fails.

By changing `~do.call(.f, c(.x, args))` to `~do.call(.f, list(.x, args))`, the function works when `args` is `NULL`, but fails when `args` is supplied (due to nested lists, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129673/passing-list-of-named-parameters-to-function)).

Is there a way to define the function so that it will work whether or not `args` is supplied?

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)
dat <- tibble(group = sample(letters, 10),
              var1 = c(rnorm(9), NA),
              var2 = rnorm(10))

my_func <- function(df, ..., .f = sum, args = NULL) {
  df %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows(
      dplyr::summarize_at(., dplyr::vars(...), ~do.call(.f, c(.x, args)))
    )
}

my_func(dat, var1, var2, .f = sum, args = list(na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#>    group    var1   var2
#>    <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 p     -0.575  -0.110
#>  2 v     -0.547  -0.511
#>  3 e     -0.564  -0.911
#>  4 l     -0.890  -0.837
#>  5 o     -0.477   2.42 
#>  6 i     -0.998   0.134
#>  7 x     -0.776  -0.491
#>  8 f      0.0645 -0.441
#>  9 z      0.959   0.460
#> 10 d     NA      -0.694
#> 11 <NA>  -3.80   -0.985


my_func(dat, var1, var2, .f = sum)
#> Error: `summarise()` argument `var1` errored.
#> ℹ `var1` is `(structure(function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) ...`.
#> x second argument must be a list
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be find if you use `c()` but make sure your first parameter is a list

```
my_func <- function(df, ..., .f = sum, args = NULL) {
  df %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows(
      dplyr::summarize_at(., dplyr::vars(...), ~do.call(.f, c(list(.x), args)))
    )
}
```